# How to store number of iterations of function fminunc in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

How can I store the number of iterations that is used to find the minimum of a function using the function fminunc in Matlab? I know I can display the number of iterations using 'options', but how can I save it to a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return four arguments. From the help for `fminunc`:

> [X,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT] = fminunc(FUN,X0,...) returns a structure 
>       OUTPUT with the number of iterations taken in OUTPUT.iterations, the 
>       number of function evaluations in OUTPUT.funcCount, the algorithm used 
>       in OUTPUT.algorithm, the number of CG iterations (if used) in
>       OUTPUT.cgiterations, the first-order optimality (if used) in
>       OUTPUT.firstorderopt, and the exit message in OUTPUT.message.

See also the [online documentation describing output arguments](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html#f475253).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I get the following error message: 'Too many output arguments'. How could that be?

Comment: @rbm: I can't say without knowing what your call to `fminunc` looks like. Also what `version` of Matlab are you using?

Comment: I used the following code: e = @(b) norm((y - XE(:,1)*b(1) - XE(:,2)*b(2))); options = optimset('Display','Iter');
[bQN, ~, ~, output] = fminunc(e, [200,0], options)';

Comment: I use Matlab version R2013a btw.

Comment: @rbm: Are you trying to apply a conjugate transpose to the `bQN ` output of `fminunc`? You can't do that on the same line if you return more than one argument.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot, I should've noticed that. I appreciate your help :)!